# how to disable keyboard during printing in terminal in golang

Tags: go

I'm writing a text interface in golang, and if you type while it's printing, it will interfere with the text being presented.  I know "stty -echo" will stop echoing the keyboard's output and "stty echo" reenables it, but when I write functions like:

```
func disableKeyboard() {
  c := exec.Command("stty -echo")
  c.Stdout = os.Stdout
  c.Run()
}

func enableKeyboard() {
  c := exec.Command("stty echo")
  c.Stdout = os.Stdout
  c.Run()
}
```

these have no impact on my programs output.  Is there something wrong with the way I'm sending these commands?

Something like:

```
disableKeyboard()
time.Sleep(time.Second)
enableKeyboard()
```

doesn't work.  I'm using a mac currently.

Comment: When you use `exec.Command`, you're forking out to a new background process. It won't affect the TTY the user is using to interact with your application.

Comment: that's what I was thinking, is there a way around this so I can disable to keyboard temporarily in the current process?

Comment: Note that `stty -echo` doesn't "disable the keyboard", rather it disables echoing the input from the keyboard. Keyboard input is still processed (or not) normally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [crypto/ssh/terminal package](https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/master/ssh/terminal/util.go#L104) (which isn't standard lib for some reason) has code that does what you need, though it uses pretty low-level syscalls to make it happen.  You can probably adapt it to what you're trying to do (by using `syscall.Stdin` as the file descriptor).  As Flimzy pointed out, though, this still doesn't disable keyboard input, it simply suppresses it from echoing to terminal, so you may still have to flush the input if you depend on it later.